# datepicker that pops up and doesn't allow to enter value manually

Tags: datetime, xpages

I have a one page application in which the user needs to fill in data.
One field is a date time field in a panel. I would like that when rendering the Panel with this date time field , that the date time picker pops up , and that the user isn't able to enter other data than the selected date time from the picker.

I read following post [Improving user interaction with xpages date picker](https://xomino.com/2012/03/14/improving-user-interaction-with-xpages-date-picker/)

My test Xpage is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/date.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:button value="Show Panel" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.showPanel="yes";}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.showPanel=="yes"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[improveDatePicker("#{id:inputText1}")]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:panel>
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="true"
    refreshMode="norefresh">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.showPanel="NO";}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

date.js is the script from MarkyRoden :

```
`function improveDatePicker(idTag){

//Select the BUTTON within the container
var calButton = x$(idTag+"_Container", " .dijitButtonContents")
//Select the dateField
var dateField = x$(idTag)
//When focusing on the field click the button
dateField.focusin(function (){
    calButton.click()
})
//When pressing a key in the field
dateField.keypress(function(evt){
//prevent the event from completing
    evt.preventDefault()
})

}`
```

When the panel is displayed, I still have to click to open the picker. Once I select a date , I can still remove it from the editbox but can't edit it.
How can I have the date time picker popping up when rendering the panel ?

Comment: `onClientLoad` is a client-side JavaScript event. You've got SSJS in the second one. I believe it also only triggers on initial page load, not on any rendering event. It's worth verifying that your code is running when you expect it to, with a basic alert prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`view.postScript()` can be used in SSJS to send CSJS to run after the relevant refresh. Use that in the "Show Panel" button to run the CSJS you wish.